# Why there are two collect in my query in spark?

Tags: join, apache-spark, cluster-computing, apache-spark-sql

I submit a query like this:

```
select key0 from BigTable,SmallTable where importedKey=keySmallTable
```

using a BroadcastHashJoin and i monitoring what append on spark with SparkUi:

[image]

Why there are two "collect at BroadcastHashJoin"?